# retrieving xml element value by searching the element by substring in its name

Tags: python, xpath, lxml, elementtree

I would need to retrieve xml element value by searching the element by substring in its name, eg. I would need to get value for all elements in XML file which names contains `client`.

I found a way how to find element with xpath by an attribute, but I haven't find a way for element name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're really using lxml (you have the question tagged both lxml and elementtree), you can use the xpath function `contains()` in a predicate...

```py
from lxml import etree

xml = """
<doc>
    <client1>foo</client1>
    <some_client>bar</some_client>
</doc>
"""

root = etree.fromstring(xml)

for elem in root.xpath("//*[contains(name(),'client')]"):
    print(f"{elem.tag}: {elem.text}")
```

printed output...

```
client1: foo
some_client: bar
```

ElementTree only has [limited xpath support](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xpath-support), so one option is to check the name of the element using the `.tag` property...

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree

xml = """
<doc>
    <client1>foo</client1>
    <some_client>bar</some_client>
</doc>
"""

root = etree.fromstring(xml)

for elem in root.iter():
    if "client" in elem.tag:
        print(f"{elem.tag}: {elem.text}")
```

This produces the same printed output above.

Comment: thanks @Daniel Haley, is there a way how to do that in ElementTree as well?

Comment: @JanFi86 - Not through xpath. ElementTree only provides [limited support](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xpath-support). You'd have to check every elements name (the `.tag` property like shown in my print() example). Let me know if you'd like me to update my answer with an example.

Comment: I would appreciate If you would add ElementTree example as well, thanks

Comment: @JanFi86 - Answer updated. Hopefully that helps.